# Enviar foto da câmera para o Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, google-storage

Preciso fazer com que meu *App* abra a câmera, tire uma foto e ao voltar para o *Fragment* anterior e clicar no botão "Upload", enviar essa foto para o *Firebase Storage*.

Consegui fazer com imagens que já estão salvas no celular, mas com a câmera não funciona, o seguinte erro é exibido:

> An unknownerror occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response

Mas o procedimento de envio é o mesmo!

Procedimento para abrir a câmera no *onClick*:

```
public void abrirCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA);
}
```

Método *onStartResultActivity*:

```
case PICK_IMAGE_CAMERA:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        filePath = escreveImagens(bitmap);
        foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    break;
```

Função *escreveImagens* utilizada acima:

```
public Uri escreveImagens(Bitmap bmp) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

            FileOutputStream pos = new FileOutputStream(nomeArquivo);
            pos.write(bytes);
            pos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Uri.parse(nomeArquivo);
}
```

Procedimento de upload das imagens:

```
   private void uploadImagem() {
        if (filePath != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Enviando...");
            progressDialog.show();
            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("Fotos/" + alunoLogado.getMatricula());

            reference.putFile(filePath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foto enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressDialog.setMessage((((int) progress) + "% enviados..."));
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ocorreu um erro. Tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```